# How to store output of exec() command in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Linux web server running a PHP/HTML page.

I need to save an output that has to interpreted as an array -

```
    exec($instruction);
```

where the output will be

```
    1 2 5 7 0 5 3 4
```

and I must be able to call out particular element in the array

```
    echo $result[4]
```

so far the following attempts were unsuccessful

```
    $result =exec($instruction); 
    or
    $result = array(exec($instruction));
```

Update,
So far I tried this -

```
$result = shell_exec($instruction);
$out = explode(" ",$result);
```

I got the expected output, but why doesn't exxplode() return individual elements?

```
Array ( [0] => 1 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 )
```

Comment: explode on the space ?

Comment: Thanks, That solves the part where I have to separate the output, but I'm still not able to get exec() command to output  an array. May be there is a better instruction?

Comment: exec will return a string, which you then convert in to an array via explode. `$result =exec($instruction); $result_array=explode(' ',$result);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result =exec($instruction); 
$result_array=explode(' ',$result);
```

or just

```
$result =explode(' ',exec($instruction));
```

Comment: Thanks Dagon, This worked for me. I found out my $instruction variable also had problems passing the command. Linked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545949/how-to-escape-characters-while-passing-system-command-in-php

Comment: whats the exact string returned?

Comment: they are probably not spaces but something else that looks like it. try `var_dump($result);`  and see what that returns

Comment: This is output from var_dump()  `string(20) "1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 "`

Comment: worth a try `preg_split('/\s+/', $result) `

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8ftEks `print_r(preg_split('/\s+/', '1 2
3 4 '));` 


`print_r(explode(' ','1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1'));`

Comment: Nope, still no success. `string(20) "1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 " Array ( [0] => 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 )`. How do I split the string into an array for every alternate character?

Comment: I do get the array when I try this `print_r(preg_split('/\s+/', '1 2 3 4 ')); print_r(explode(' ','1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1'));`  `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 0 [7] => 1 [8] => 0 [9] => 1 )`. But how come the $output from shell_exec() doesn't get split?

Comment: i suspect they are not actually spaces but something else, tabs line breaks other ? whats this one give you `print_r(str_split($result));`

Comment: Success!! But strangely `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [2] => 2 [3] => [4] => 2 [5] => [6] => 1 [7] => [8] => 1 [9] => [10] => 1 [11] => [12] => 0 [13] => [14] => 0 [15] => [16] => 1 [17] => [18] => 1 [19] => ) `. As per your suspicion seems like it may be line breaks returned from shell.

Comment: the preg_split example should split on line breaks

Comment: It was newline that was being printed! `$output = explode("\n",$result);`. Thanks Dagon!

Answer (score 14):

According to documentation ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)) exec has a second parameter that is passed by reference called $output. So you can try:

```
exec($instruction, $results);
```

And then you can access $results that will be an array with each line as an element. So:

```
$results[0]
```

will have the first line of your output.

Answer (score 4):

Why explode did not work for me? 
The shell $instruction that I used returned "newline" or "\n". I had to split the string using "\n" as the delimiter.
This worked for me -

```
$result = shell_exec($instruction);
$out = explode("\n",$result);
```

Comment: This mode will only save the last iteration. ie, if you have more than 1 named process, like iexplorer windows you will get only last. Consider to use `$result[] = shell_exec($instruction);
$out = explode("\n",$result[0]);` to archieve the same result, but you can be sure about how many proceses you close by count($result).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use:

```
$result = shell_exec($instruction);
$out = explode("\n",$result);
```

Because shell_exec function returns the complete output as string. If you have more than one line, you should use that.