# How to Escape characters while passing system command in PHP

Tags: php

I have a Linux web server running a PHP/HTML page.

```
    for loop
    {
    $instruction= "I'm constructing the instruction here";
    }
    $instruction = "lspci | grep -i vga | awk '{print $1}' & lspci | grep -i RAID | awk '{print $1}'";
    $result = exec($instruction); `
```

I'm unable to get the exact output as below,

```
    echo $result
    08:03.0 07:00.0
```

Seems like some of the characters have to be escaped in order for exec() to work. 
How and what characters do I need to escape?

Note:

```
    07:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic LSI MegaSAS 9260 (rev 05)
    08:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Graphics, Inc. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`escapeshellcmd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) in PHP

Something like..

```
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
exec($escaped_command);
```

Alternatively, you could make use of [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('ls '.escapeshellarg($userdata));
```

Comment: Thanks but this escapes characters from the command, but command does not get executed - Output of escapeshellcmd() `lspci \| grep -i vga \| awk '\{print \$1\}' \& lspci \| grep -i RAID \| awk '\{print \$1\}'`

Comment: @bhp, Do something like in the example mentioned and also in the new edited answer.