# Reading a file name with spaces and ()

Tags: php

I've wrote a script to read .pdf files. Everything works ok if filename is something like **document.pdf** but sometimes I receive files with **document (1).pdf** and the script fails.
Following is the code

Any idea?

```
$dir = $_POST['dir'];

$fname = basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']); 

$full_fname = $dir.$fname;

$command ='/usr/bin/pdftotext  -layout '.$full_fname.' -';

$content = exec($command, $output, $returnvar);

$count = count($output);

if ($count == 0) {die("Sorry but cant open the file. Maybe the filename contains () or unwanted chars");}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: You need single quotes around the file name in the exec command. Something like: `"/usr/bin/pdftotext  -layout '".$full_fname."' -"`. Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Escape characters while passing system command in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545949/how-to-escape-characters-while-passing-system-command-in-php)

Comment: Never pass untrusted input to shell commands. Consider what happens if the client sends a file named `; rm -rf /`. You must *always* escape user input for the context it is used in.

Comment: Thank you guys. Your suggestions were what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do no use `$_FILES['filename']['name']` but `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']`.

The `name` field contains the name the uploader *claims* the file to have on their local file system. This name can be used (after proper output escaping) to give the user a reference.

The `tmp_name` is a file name under which the file is stored in a temporary location by PHP after upload. This filename is randomly system generated and free from user injection. But mind that you have to copy/move the file (best using [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)) to a permanent storage place (best outside your document root) in case you need the file later on.

If you ever pass data to command line use [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) For instance:

```
$fname_escaped = escapeshellarg($_FILE['filename']['tmp_name']);
$command ='/usr/bin/pdftotext  -layout '.$fname_escaped.' -';
```

(Yes, even the tmp name, which is most likely safe has to be escaped, both to prevent potential future issues, as well as simplifying cod review)

When printing to the user always escape data, depending on the context, using [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) or similar:

```
$fname_html = htmlentties($_FILE['filename']['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
echo "Thank you for uploading <i>{$fname_html}</i>.";
```

Such escaping should also be done on the result of an external pogram like `pdftotext`.

When storing the name to a database use the proper escaping routines or parameter binding.

Always, for all data coming from outside your program.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression. suppose your `$fname` look like **document (1).pdf** (one spaces or more then one spaces) would come out as **document_(1).pdf**.

```
$fname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $fname);
// output : document_(1).pdf you get this output...

// Or Removing All special characters and spaces from filename
$fname = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-\.]/i", '', $fname);
// output : document_1.pdf you get this output...
```